# Convergence rate for $\int_{\{f\ge n\}}|f(x)|\,dx$ for $f\in L^1(\Omega)$

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^d$ be open and bounded and $f\in L^1(\Omega)$. Consider the following sequence indedxed by $n\in\mathbb N$:
$$ \int_{\{f\ge n\}}|f(x)|\,dx .$$
This sequence converges to zero by the Beppo Levi-theorem. 
My question: Can one find an explicit convergence rate which is independent of $f$? More specifically, I'm looking for something along the lines of
$$\int_{\{f\ge n\}}|f(x)|\,dx\leq C_f n^{-\alpha},$$ 
with some $\alpha>0$ and a constant $C_f$ which is allowed to depend on $f$.

Comment: No hope... For every sequence $(a_n)$ decreasing to $0$ there exists some integrable function $f$ such that, for every $n$, $$\int_{\{f\ge n\}}|f(x)|\,dx=a_n$$

Comment: You are using $n$ in two ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this is only a partial answer)

consider $\Omega=(0,1)$, 
$f=x^\beta, 0>\beta>-1$.

We have $f \geq n \Leftrightarrow x \leq n^{\beta^{-1}}$.

Then
$$
\int_{f\geq n} |f| = \int_0^{n^{\beta^{-1}}} x^\beta \mathrm dx
= \frac{{(n^{\beta^{-1}})}^{\beta+1}}{\beta+1}
= \frac{n^{1+\beta^{-1}}}{\beta+1}
$$

Because $\beta$ can be arbitrarily close to $-1$, the value $\alpha:=-1-\beta^{-1}$ can be arbitrarily small.

So the convergence rate is worse than $n^{-\alpha}$ for every $\alpha>0$, when $\alpha$ has to be independent of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I guess, one can show in the same way that there's also no log-type convergence rate, or any other... So the statement I hoped for really seems to be just wrong.